# How to understand the spring reference documentation regarding @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-annotations

Hopefully this question is simple enough.  I'm reading the [Spring Framework Reference:beans-java](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) section and I came across this usage example
[image]

The part that confuses me is the note at the end, specifically where it says

> Note also that there is no need to specify @Autowired if the target
>   bean defines only one constructor; in the example above, @Autowired is
>   not necessary on the RepositoryConfig constructor.

I don't quite understand why I can remove `@Autowired` from `RepositoryConfig()`? What is the target bean in this case and what constructor are they referring to?

I attempted to reproduce this but the documentation doesn't provide the `AccountRepository` class or the `TransferService` class and I'm a noob so not sure what they should like look.  So a reproducible example would be desirable.

Comment: The note mentions the `RepositoryConfig` class, which is the target bean, and they are referring to its constructor.

Comment: I'm confused about your misunderstanding. The quote says _`@Autowired` is not necessary on the `RepositoryConfig` constructor._ So `RepositoryConfig` is the bean (class) and, since it has a single constructor, doesn't require the `@Autowired` on that constructor.

Comment: as I said I'm a noob (which is why I was reading documentation).  The "target bean" threw me off because a parameter of the RepositoryConfig constructor uses the Datasource bean.  When you explain it - sure it makes sense now, but it didn't click for me.  I tried to reproduce it but the code was not complete (although now I think about it I could test it with my own code)  so I did make an effort to figure it out and did some searching online.  I don't appreciate the down votes.  I'm still not clear on what makes RepositoryConfig a bean, since the class has 3 annotations, is it any of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring version before 4.3 required you to annotate the constructor you wanted to use with `@Autowired`. Even if your class had a single constructor.

As of Spring 4.3 when your class has a single constructor you can leave out the `@Autowired` on the constructor as Spring then automatically assumes you want to use that constructor.

See [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3) for more information and [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12278) the Jira ticket.